# Returning thumbnail file path from camera

Tags: android, cordova

So I forked the [cordova camera plugin](https://github.com/JoeKomputer/cordova-plugin-camera) because I wanted to modify it to return both a thumbnail and a regular size image when a picture is taken. I've never done android development before but this is what I have so far:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    // Get src and dest types from request code
    int srcType = (requestCode / 16) - 1;
    int destType = (requestCode % 16) - 1;
    // if camera crop
if (requestCode == CROP_CAMERA) {
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Bitmap thumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(croppedUri.toString()), 100, 100);
    Uri thumbNailUri = getImageUri(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), thumbImage);
    JSONArray imageArray = new JSONArray();
    imageArray.put(croppedUri.toString());
    imageArray.put(thumbNailUri.toString());
    this.callbackContext
        .success(imageArray);
    croppedUri = null;

  }// If cancelled
  else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
    this.failPicture("Camera cancelled.");
  }

  // If something else
  else {
    this.failPicture("Did not complete!");
  }

}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
      String path = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
      return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

The problem is the application crashes when executing this code. It seems that the call `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(croppedUri.toString())` returns a null value.

All the code I'm working with is [here](https://github.com/JoeKomputer/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/CameraLauncher.java) within the repo I linked above. All I'm trying to do is return the image paths to both the regular size image and the thumbnail.

Comment: Why not just convert the image to a thumbnail after getting the full size image from the plugin using a canvas element?

Comment: That's an option, but I figured doing it natively would be more performant.

Comment: Where does croppedUri come in? It seems like in the scenario here you'd always have croppedUri as null.